# Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio is there a Query name header like feature?

Tags: sql-server-2008

So linqpad allows you to name queries so that when you run the query it comes up as a header to the query itself when you click run- this helps when you have multiple selects going on at the same time: is there a similar feature on MSQL mgmt studio?

so, I.E. when queried, rather than

```
 Query1Table1|Query1Table2|Query1Table3
 Query2Table1|Query2Table2|Query2Table3
 Query3Table1|Query3Table2|Query3Table3
```

you could see

```
    'People'
 Query1Table1|Query1Table2|Query1Table3
    'Students'
 Query2Table1|Query2Table2|Query2Table3
    'class'
 Query3Table1|Query3Table2|Query3Table3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not that I've seen. If you're looking for the ability to add some verbose/debugging values to your results, you could do a one-off select before your actual select. You can wrap these statements in an If @debug check so you can selectively turn them on/off easily. I do this for some of our more complicated queries to help with debugging, especially when there are table variables used. As a simple example:

```
declare @debug bit;set @debug=1;

declare @t table (id int)
insert into @t select 1
insert into @t select 2
insert into @t select 3
insert into @t select 4
insert into @t select 5

-- Debugging
if (@debug=1) begin
select '@T contents:';
select * from @t
end

-- Actual select
select * from @t where id >3;
```

Comment: Thanks- it's too bad they don't have it. i guess i'll just use linqpad then. the debugging bit is useful as well